# upgrade solr from 4.2.1 to 5.3.1

Tags: solr

I've been tasked with migrating from our solr 4.2.1 server to a new solr server, 5.3.1.  I was hoping I could just pick up the cores, and move them over with a little but of editing files.  But atlas, I can't quite figure it out.

I have tried moving a single core, and creating a core.properties files with the name of the core and I get:

testcore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler'

Any thoughts as to what the problem might be?  Any thoughts would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the final stages of the similar upgrade; here is how I suggest you proceed.

1. Install both versions side by side and create the collection in new solr
2. Take your default schema/solrconfig from the new solr and move stuff into it from your old schema/solrconfig. The formatting changed, so you will need to manually move all of your config.
3. Make sure that works
4. Move the indexes - once your solrconfig and schema match up you should be able to use your old indexes (data directory).
5. To complete the upgrade you will need to re-index into a new but similar collection. This will upgrade the underlying lucene indexes. Your new version of solr has cursor mark support so it becomes much simplier; especially if you are using collection aliases.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does [not have its own request handler any longer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) (changed in 4.x, removed in 5.x). It has now been merged into the standard `solr.UpdateRequestHandler`, and the request handler is selected internally based on the `Content-Type` header of the request.